# How to make statistic according to week unit in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
            usr1   usr2
2016-01-01  20     NaN
2016-01-02  13     12
2016-01-03  NaN    12
2016-01-04  NaN    23
2016-01-05  13     21
2016-01-06  20     NaN
2016-01-07  NaN    12
2016-01-08  NaN    23
2016-01-09  13     21
2016-01-10  20     NaN
.           .      .
.           .      .
```

the index is the date, and what I want to do is trying to get the sum of every week(period is 7 days,from Monday to Sunday),and the result will be like this:

```
            usr1   usr2
week1       33     24
week2       13     12
week3       66     100
.           .      .
.           .      .
```

How can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.resample()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df.resample('W').sum()
```

If you don't want to keep the `date_time` values that indicate when the weeks occurred, you can `.reset_index(drop=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

Some more statistics

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('W')).describe().dropna()
```

[image]